# How to make OnclickListener work right inside for loop?

Tags: java, android, google-maps, onclicklistener, google-maps-api-2

I have an hashmap of (Integer; PlayerMarkerAndStatus) pair for storing Player id and PlayerMarkerAndStatus object. PlayerMarkerAndStatus has a marker and current status for player id specified in HashMap.

I also have volley request to API which returns details of each player of hashmap on success case of Volley - `OnSuccess(Player2 nearbyPlayer)`. Those data is supposed to be sent to a fragment when a marker is clicked - `onMarkerClick(Marker marker)`.

It compares a clicked marker and a marker from the hashmap. If they have equal marker IDs, it sends this player's details to the fragment. However, OnMarkerClickListener only takes the last marker of HashMap to compare with a clicked marker.

It is my code below:

```
for (final Map.Entry<Integer, PlayerMarkerAndStatus> e :
                    player_id_marker_status.entrySet()) {
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "marker id of current entry: " + e.getValue().getMarker().getId());
                getNearbyPlayerDetails(new VolleyCallbackNearbyPlayerDetails() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(final Player2 nearbyPlayer) {
                        mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
                                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "clicked marker id: " + marker.getId());
                                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "current marker id: " + e.getValue().getMarker().getId());

                                if (marker.getId().equals(e.getValue().getMarker().getId())) {
                                    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "marker clicked. Player id: " + e.getKey());

                                    PlayerDetailsFragment playerDetailsFragment =
                                            new PlayerDetailsFragment();

                                    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                                    bundle.putString("player_details_username",
                                            nearbyPlayer.getSurname());
                                    if (nearbyPlayer.getType() == -1)
                                        bundle.putString("player_details_type", "a");
                                    else {
                                        bundle.putString("player__details_type", "b");
                                    }
                                    bundle.putInt("player_details_health",
                                            nearbyPlayer.getHealth());

                                    playerDetailsFragment.setArguments(bundle);
                                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                                            .add(R.id.player_details_fragment_container,
                                                    playerDetailsFragment).commit();

                                    return true;
                                }
                                return false;
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }, e.getKey());
            }
```

Logs of HashMap:

```
09-22 11:37:42.410 23553-23553/com.orujzade.asdf D/MainActivity:  marker id of current entry: m3
09-22 11:37:42.415 23553-23553/com.orujzade.asdf D/MainActivity: marker id of current entry: m2
09-22 11:37:42.415 23553-23553/com.orujzade.asdf D/MainActivity: marker id of current entry: m1
```

Logs on marker click:

```
09-22 11:39:15.353 23553-23553/com.orujzade.asdf D/MainActivity: clicked marker id: m3
09-22 11:39:15.353 23553-23553/com.orujzade.asdf D/MainActivity: current marker id: m1
09-22 11:39:20.593 23553-23553/com.orujzade.asdf D/MainActivity: clicked marker id: m2
09-22 11:39:20.593 23553-23553/com.orujzade.asdf D/MainActivity: current marker id: m1
09-22 11:39:25.593 23553-23553/com.orujzade.asdf D/MainActivity: clicked marker id: m4
09-22 11:39:25.593 23553-23553/com.orujzade.asdf D/MainActivity: current marker id: m1
```

How can I make `OnMarkerClickListener` take a right marker from the hashmap?

Comment: show your for loop code too

Comment: where you're initialising `mMap `?

Comment: @RahulSharma what `for` loop?

Comment: @Pr38y, it is `onMapReady(Google googleMap)`  method which basically assign map type to `GoogleMap mMap` - `mMap = googleMap;
        mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define one HashMap into class level to get player from marker id :

```
HashMap<String, Player2> playerMap = new HashMap<>();
```

Iterate `HashMap` and get player from above define method :

```
for (final Map.Entry<Integer, PlayerMarkerAndStatus> e : player_id_marker_status.entrySet()) {
     Log.d(LOG_TAG, "marker id of current entry: " + e.getValue().getMarker().getId());
     getNearbyPlayer(e.getKey(),e.getValue().getMarker().getId());
}
```

Define one method to get player using volley request and set player into `HashMap` using marker as key :

```
public void getNearbyPlayer(Integer playerId,final String markerId) {
        getNearbyPlayerDetails(new VolleyCallbackNearbyPlayerDetails() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(final Player2 nearbyPlayer) {
                playerMap.put(markerId, nearbyPlayer);
            }
        },playerId);
}
```

At last define marker click listener and get player from marker id :

```
mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
       @Override
       public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
          Log.d(LOG_TAG, "clicked marker id: " + marker.getId());
          Player2 nearbyPlayer = playerMap.get(marker.getId());
          PlayerDetailsFragment playerDetailsFragment = new PlayerDetailsFragment();
          Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
          bundle.putString("player_details_username", nearbyPlayer.getSurname());
          if (nearbyPlayer.getType() == -1){ 
              bundle.putString("player_details_type", "a");
          }else {
              bundle.putString("player__details_type", "b");
          }
          bundle.putInt("player_details_health", nearbyPlayer.getHealth());
          playerDetailsFragment.setArguments(bundle);
          getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.player_details_fragment_container, playerDetailsFragment).commit();
          return true;
      }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`setOnMarkerClickListener` should be out of loop. Create one hashmap `idPlayerMap` for player id and `Player2`. in volley success response, put that `Player2` object with it's id in that map. In the `MarkerClickListener` run a loop to check which marker has been clicked and get corresponding player from `idPlayerMap` and send it to required `Fragment`.

```
 mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
                                      @Override
                                      public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
                                          Log.d(LOG_TAG, "clicked marker id: " + marker.getId());
                                          Log.d(LOG_TAG, "current marker id: " + e.getValue().getMarker().getId());
                                          for (final Map.Entry<Integer, PlayerMarkerAndStatus> e :
                                                  player_id_marker_status.entrySet()) {
                                              Log.d(LOG_TAG, "marker id of current entry: " + e.getValue().getMarker().getId());
                                              if (marker.getId().equals(e.getValue().getMarker().getId())) {
                                                  Log.d(LOG_TAG, "marker clicked. Player id: " + e.getKey());

                                                  PlayerDetailsFragment playerDetailsFragment =
                                                          new PlayerDetailsFragment();
                                                  Player2 nearbyPlayer = idPlayerMap.get(e.getKey());
                                                  Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                                                  bundle.putString("player_details_username",
                                                          nearbyPlayer.getSurname());
                                                  if (nearbyPlayer.getType() == -1)
                                                      bundle.putString("player_details_type", "a");
                                                  else {
                                                      bundle.putString("player__details_type", "b");
                                                  }
                                                  bundle.putInt("player_details_health",
                                                          nearbyPlayer.getHealth());

                                                  playerDetailsFragment.setArguments(bundle);
                                                  getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                                                          .add(R.id.player_details_fragment_container,
                                                                  playerDetailsFragment).commit();

                                                  return true;
                                              }
                                              return false;
                                          }
                                      }
                                      HashMap<Integer, Player2> idPlayerMap =  new HashMap<Integer, Player2>();

    for (final Map.Entry<Integer, PlayerMarkerAndStatus> e :
            player_id_marker_status.entrySet()) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "marker id of current entry: " + e.getValue().getMarker().getId());
        getNearbyPlayerDetails(new VolleyCallbackNearbyPlayerDetails() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Player2 nearbyPlayer) {
                idPlayerMap.put(e.getKey(), nearbyPlayer);
                });
            }
        }
    }
```